# MPI send a struct which contains dynamic arrays

Tags: c, mpi

By using MPI I want to send a struct which contains a dynamic array of another kind of struct. To complicate matters, this last in turn contains a dynamic array of char.

I defined the following solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct Code {
  char character;
  int length;
  char *code;
} Code;

typedef struct CodeDictionary {
  int codesNr;
  Code *codes;
} CodeDictionary;

static const int CODE_NR = 5;

void buildCodeType(MPI_Datatype *codeType) {
    int blockLen[2] = {1, 1};
    MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_CHAR, MPI_INT};
    
    MPI_Aint offsets[2];
    offsets[0] = offsetof(Code, character);
    offsets[1] = offsetof(Code, length);

    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blockLen, offsets, types, codeType);
    MPI_Type_commit(codeType);
}

int getRand(int from, int to)
{
    int num = (rand() % (to - from + 1)) + from;
    return num;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int procNumber;
    int pid; 

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procNumber);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);

    if (procNumber < 2) {
        printf("At least two processes required.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const int from = 1;
    const int to = 9;

    srand(time(0));

    MPI_Datatype codeType;
    buildCodeType(&codeType);

    if (pid == 0) {
        CodeDictionary sndDict = {.codesNr = CODE_NR, .codes = calloc(CODE_NR, sizeof(Code))};

        // create some fake values
        for (int i = 0; i < CODE_NR; i++) {
            sndDict.codes[i].character = 'a' + i;
            sndDict.codes[i].length = getRand(from, to);
            sndDict.codes[i].code = calloc(sndDict.codes[i].length, sizeof(char));

            for (int j = 0; j < sndDict.codes[i].length; j++) {
                int randChar = getRand('a', 'z');
                sndDict.codes[i].code[j] = randChar + j;
            }
        }

        printf("source data\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < sndDict.codesNr; i++) {
            printf("codes[%d]:\n\t", i);

            printf("character: %c\tlength: %d\tcode: ", sndDict.codes[i].character, sndDict.codes[i].length);
            for (int j = 0; j < sndDict.codes[i].length; j++)
                printf("%c", sndDict.codes[i].code[j]);

            printf("\n");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < procNumber; i++) { // maybe I can use MPI_Bcast
            MPI_Send(&sndDict.codesNr, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            for (int j = 0; j < sndDict.codesNr; j++) {
                MPI_Send(&sndDict.codes[j], 1, codeType, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(sndDict.codes[j].code, sndDict.codes[j].length, MPI_CHAR, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sndDict.codesNr; i++)
            free(sndDict.codes[i].code);

    } else {
        MPI_Status status;
        CodeDictionary rcvDict = {.codesNr = 0, .codes = NULL};

        MPI_Recv(&rcvDict.codesNr, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        rcvDict.codes = calloc(rcvDict.codesNr, sizeof(Code));
        for (int i = 0; i < rcvDict.codesNr; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&rcvDict.codes[i], 1, codeType, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            
            rcvDict.codes[i].code = calloc(rcvDict.codes[i].length, sizeof(char));
            MPI_Recv(rcvDict.codes[i].code, rcvDict.codes[i].length, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }

       printf("\nreceived data\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < rcvDict.codesNr; i++) {
            printf("codes[%d]:\n\t", i);

            printf("character: %c\tlength: %d\tcode: ", rcvDict.codes[i].character, rcvDict.codes[i].length);
            for (int j = 0; j < rcvDict.codes[i].length; j++)
                printf("%c", rcvDict.codes[i].code[j]);

            printf("\n");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rcvDict.codesNr; i++)
            free(rcvDict.codes[i].code);
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&codeType);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I learned that I have to send first the size of the dynamic data, and then this last, otherwise I cannot allocate correctly the needed memory. Anyway I find this solution a bit complicated.

I'm developing in C and compiling with mpicc.

Do you know if there is a smarter solution?

Comment: A pointer on one process has no meaning when you send it to another. Send the data, then recreate the pointers. Use `MPI_Pack` would be one way of dealing with dynamic data.

Comment: An alternative, if applicable, is to replace `char *code` with `char code[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]`